Notation in Lovasz Exercise 2.6
In Lovasz's Combinatorial Problems and Exercise, 2.6, he says "Let $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ be any events, and $B_i=f_i(A_,\ldots, A_n)$ polynomials in the $A_1,\ldots, A_n$. Then, he goes on to speak about the probability $P(B_i)$. How do you think of polynomials of events as events in a probability space?

Any measurable function of random variables is a random variable, for example, you can study the law of $Y=X^2$ by asking questions like $P(Y\leq 4)=P(-2\leq X \leq 2)$.

@caduk The question is: what is a "polynomial" whose arguments are events and whose value is also an event? I believe this refers to expressions you can obtain by combining $A_1, \dots, A_n$ using unions, intersections, and complements. For example, $B_1=(A_1\cup A_3)\cap A_2^C$. (In other words, such a polynomial is any of the $2^{(2^n)}$ events which are measurable with respect to the sigma-algebra generated by the events $A_1, \dots, A_n$.) I'm not sure if this use of the word "polynomial" is particularly standard (but maybe it's a natural usage in some contexts).

@NicholasBurbank, ok I didn't see it was referring to event and not random variables. My interpretation is that the events are sampled in $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$,  but indeed, the exercise is not very precise, even after searching for the full exercise, I could not get the precise meaning from the context. It would be good to add the full exercise in the question.

In fact, I think you are right on the interpretation, it seems to be the one used in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X83900638, where they refer to boolean polynomials.
